# Show that for any value of theta, $f_1$ and $g_1$ are vectors in $W$; 2. Show that $f_1$ and $g_1$ for a basis for $W$

Tags: linear-algebra

Full question:

Let $W$ be the space spanned by $f=\sin(x)$ and $g=\cos(x)$.

(a) Show that for any value of $\theta$, $f_1=\sin(x+\theta)$ and $g_1=\cos(x+\theta)$ are vectors in $W$.

(b) Show that $f_1$ and $g_1$ form a basis for $W$.

It may be late and the theta is throwing me off--is (a) asking for me to prove that $f_1$ and $g_1$ are linear combinations of $W$? If so, I'm still confused about the $\theta$.

For (b), I'm aware that one must show that the two vectors span $W$ and are linearly independent.

I think the trig is just throwing me off. I'm used to having basic vectors (e.g. $\{(1,2,3),(2,3,4),...\} )$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Is asking if the function $f_1$ is an element of $W$.

$W$, by definition, is a linear space spanned by $f$ and $g$, and a linear space is a set of all *linear combinations* of the two functions. So, what you really need to prove is that $f_1$ is a linear combination of $f$ and $g$, or in other words, that there exist two real numbers $\alpha, \beta$ such that $\alpha f + \beta g = f_1$.

To solve this, a simple **hint**:

> Trigonometric addition formulae.

For (b), it's easiest to show that $f$ and $g$ are elements of the span of $f_1, g_1$. This, along with (a), proves that the two spans (the span of $f,g$ and the span of $f_1,g_1$) must be equal.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. I haven't taken Trig in almost a decade; I'm getting back into classes again. Thank you!

Comment: @d3m0nxdrums Good to know my answer helped. Good luck with the classes!